# Question on how to split a string into an array of desired strings in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a question.

There are several ways to divide a string into a string array.

First of all, the way I made a string into a string array is,

```
let str = "F'2R'UU2"
let strArr: [String] = str.map { String($0) }
//strArr => ["F", "'", "2", "R", "'", "U", "U", "2"]
```

It turns into a string array like this

But I would like to divide based on the uppercase alphabet. For example, if you divide the string `F2`, it becomes `["F2"]` instead of `["F", "2"]`, and if you divide the string `F'2`, it becomes `["F", "'", "2"]` instead of `["F'2"]`

The result I want is,

```
let str = "F'2R'UU2"
<<<str to strArr>>>
//strArr => ["F'2", "R'", "U", "U2"]
```

Please let me know!

Comment: It's unclear. You want that each element of the array be the first letter + all the following non-letter in the initial text?

Comment: Yes, that's right. help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to iterate the string over each character and either append it to an array if it is an uppercase letter or add it to the last element of the array otherwise

```
let str = "F'2R'UU2"

let res = str.reduce(into: [String]()) {
    if $1.isUppercase || $0.isEmpty {
        $0.append("\($1)") 
    } else {
        $0[$0.count - 1] = $0.last! + "\($1)"
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson why not simply `$0[$0.count-1].append($1)`. One liner `$1.isUppercase || $0.isEmpty ? $0.append(String($1)) : $0[$0.count-1].append($1)`