# Convert/Split string to array at letter

Tags: swift

I know there are a lot of other threads for splitting a String by a specific separator or position. I have a little bit different case and couldn't find any similar question here.
My input string is:
`"A 300 133 Z 800 900 12 50 Q 3 -10 X"`

and the desired output is:
`[["A", "300", "133"], ["Z", "800", "900", "12", "50"], ["Q", "3", "-10"], ["X"]]`

Comment: Is there any relation, any sequence, or any concept in this string or any specific pattern?

Comment: Kind of. It starts with a letter and then appear between one and four numbers. This part is repeated multiple times. At the end the string ends with a letter.

Comment: I think I saw a similar question a couple month ago? There should be a shorter way, but that should do the trick using `reduce(into:_:)`: `let reduced2 = inputString.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).reduce(into: [[String]]()) { result, current in guard var last = result.last, !current.hasLetter() else { result.append([current]); return }; last.append(current); result[result.count - 1] = last }`

Comment: Oh, the question is a little different but yet similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252324/question-on-how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-of-desired-strings-in-swift/65252556#65252556

Answer (score 0):

First, let's separate each elements:

```
let inputString = "A 300 133 Z 800 900 12 50 Q 3 -10 X"
let elements = inputString.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
```

Then, we can use [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce): we iterate each element of the array. If it's a letter, we append it as a new sub array, if not, we append it to the last sub array.

```
let reduced = elements.reduce(into: [[String]]()) { result, current in
    guard var last = result.last,
          current.rangeOfCharacter(from: .letters) == nil else {
        result.append([current])
        return
    }
    last.append(current)
    result[result.count - 1] = last
}
```

Side note:
I used the test "is letter": "has a letter", so if you have "333D", it will return "true". The test there is to update according to your needs, I don't check if there is only one letter (as in your example, etc).